# in mvc4 click the edit button in webgrid catch the id url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, url

When I click the edit button in a webgrid it shows the id in the url like this:

```
http://localhost:12500/Product/ProductUpdate/1
```

How can I catch that id?

Comment: Could you please say more about what you are trying to achieve

Comment: you want the id on the controller? if yes,

in your ProductController

        public ActionResult ProductUpdate(int? id)
     {
          // now you can  access to the id value
       .... your code
        return View();
     }

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by splitting the spring by slashes and get the last element of it.

```
string url = "http://localhost:12500/Product/ProductUpdate/1";
string[] splited = url.Spit("/");

int id;

if (Int32.TryParse(splited[splited.Lenght - 1], out id)
{
    // id of url a number and is into variable 'id'
}
else
{
    // id is not a number
}
```